# mysqli Object Oriented Programming

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I'm trying to make my login homepage work. At the first I built my query with mysql but I  always got the error "query is empty" so I decided to change over to mysqli. I'm now getting the error "Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters".
how can I call the first parameter "$db" in my "mysqli_query($db, $string)" from the method "connect()" in  the class "database2" to make it work?
I tried with " $result = $this->cxn->query($query)" but then i got the error "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database2::query()

```php
<?php

class Login
{
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $cxn;    // Database object.

    function __construct($username, $password)
    {
        // Set data
        $this->setData($username, $password);

        // connect to db
        $this->connectToDb();

        //get Data
        $this->getData();
    }

   private function setData($username, $password){

             $this->username = $username;
             $this->password = $password;

            }

    private function connectToDb(){

            include 'models/database2.php';
            $vars = "include/vars.php";
            $this->cxn = new Database2($vars);

            }

    private function getData(){

          $query ="SELECT 'username', 'password' FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = '$this->username'
                                    AND 'password' = '$this->password'";

           $result = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
           $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result); 

                 if ($num_row>1) {
                    return TRUE;
                 }else{
                      throw new Exception("The query was not successful!");
                  }
              }

      function close(){
        $this->cxn->close_connect();
            }

}
?>
```

Database2 class:

```php
<?php


class Database2{


    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $database;

    function __construct($filename){
        if(is_file($filename)){
            include $filename;
        }else{
            throw new Exception("Error Processing Request");
            }
        $this->host     = $host;
        $this->user     = $user;
        $this->password =$password;
        $this->database =$database;

        $this->connect();       
      }

         public function connect(){
                      // connect to the server.
                     $db = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->password);    
                       if ($db->connect_errno) {
                           die("We are sorry, you could not be connected to the server,
                            plaese check your connection setting!");
                       }else{
                           echo "You are connected to the database";
                       }
                   }


      public function close_connect(){
        mysql_close();

      }
}


?>
```

i appreciate any help

Comment: What is _Project oriented programming_? Did you mean _Object Oriented Programming_?

Comment: wtf is going on with that `mysql_close();` ?

Comment: You don't store passwords as plain-text into databases. Also you don't need to keep them as private members in plain-text - if you need to keep them there at all. You normally only need the password hash at the time of authentication, that is when you query your database as the backend to check if the user has given the right password.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you use procedural style, you have to set and use a "$db" variable in the database2 class.
Set the variable in the connect function:

```
$this->db = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->password);
```

And then, you can use the $db in the database2 object

```
$result = mysqli_query($this->cxn->db, $query);
```

Comment: mysql_error does not work with mysqli. Additionally, this is not procedural style. and another hint: assing a local variable first to keep your code flexible, regardless where it comes from. Variables in PHP are pretty cheap and make your code so much better ... .

Comment: My mistake for mysql_error, sorry. But this is the procedural use of mysqli, in the object oriented style you don't have to use the "link" parameter ( http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php )
EDIT: fix mysql_error

Comment: The link you talk about *is* an object. As that procedure requires an object, that procedure itself is object oriented. Once understood it's better then to just write `$result = $this->cxn->db->query($query);`. The use of the function name `mysqli_query` does only stand in your way for that line of code (very most likely). Also you've just removed any kind of error handling, which is not suggestable. As the database is a remote service, error handling is pretty important.